# Convert JSON to full table

Tags: python, json, pandas, shopify

How with pandas convert shopify Json response

> pastebin.com/8Kf8FHf4

to full Table without column included json child

now i use this code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
import requests
def get_all_orders():
    last=0
    orders=pd.DataFrame()
    while True:
        url = f"https://{apikey}:{password}@{hostname}/admin/api/{version}/{resource}.json?limit=250&fulfillment_status=unfulfilled&since_id={last}"
        response = requests.request("GET", url)
        
        df=pd.DataFrame(response.json()['orders'])
        orders=pd.concat([orders,df])
        last=df['id'].iloc[-1]
        if len(df)<250:
            break
    return(orders)
df=get_all_orders()
```

I want get rid of that childs in columns

[image]

Comment: did you try json_normalize? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html Also - how should the final DF look like?

Comment: please see in pastebin pastebin.com/8Kf8FHf4

Comment: Post a small example of the JSON here. Enough to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: it is smalest possible example, and it too long to post here

Comment: in pastebin there is an array with 1 `order`. How should the DF look like?

Comment: each vaue should = 1 column, same like this tool do https://www.convertjson.com/json-to-html-table.htm

Comment: You could delete 3/4 of the dataset and still demonstrate the problem. Or better, just make something up that looks similar that just has a few nested dicts in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will make a flat dict for each order in the data set (trimmed since it is too big).
The result is a DF with 1 row and 166 columns

```
import collections
import pandas as pd


def flatten(d, parent_key='', sep='_'):
    items = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        new_key = parent_key + sep + k if parent_key else k
        if isinstance(v, collections.MutableMapping):
            items.extend(flatten(v, new_key, sep=sep).items())
        else:
            items.append((new_key, v))
    return dict(items)




data = {
    "orders": [
        {
            "id": 450789469,
            "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/Order/450789469",
            "app_id": None,
            "browser_ip": "0.0.0.0",
            "buyer_accepts_marketing": False,
            "cancel_reason": None,
            "cancelled_at": None,
            "cart_token": "68778783ad298f1c80c3bafcddeea02f",
            "checkout_id": 901414060,
            "checkout_token": "bd5a8aa1ecd019dd3520ff791ee3a24c",
            "client_details": {
                "accept_language": None,
                "browser_height": None,
                "browser_ip": "0.0.0.0",
                "browser_width": None,
                "session_hash": None,
                "user_agent": None
            },
            "closed_at": None,
            "confirmed": True,
            "contact_email": "bob.norman@hostmail.com",
            "created_at": "2008-01-10T11:00:00-05:00",
            "currency": "USD",
            "customer_locale": None,
            "device_id": None,
            "discount_codes": [
                {
                    "code": "TENOFF",
                    "amount": "10.00",
                    "type": "fixed_amount"
                }
            ],
            "email": "bob.norman@hostmail.com",
            "financial_status": "partially_refunded",
            "fulfillment_status": None,
            "gateway": "authorize_net",
            "landing_site": "http://www.example.com?source=abc",
            "landing_site_ref": "abc",
            "location_id": None,
            "name": "#1001",
            "note": None,
            "note_attributes": [
                {
                    "name": "custom engraving",
                    "value": "Happy Birthday"
                },
                {
                    "name": "colour",
                    "value": "green"
                }
            ],
            "number": 1,
            "order_number": 1001,
            "order_status_url": "https://apple.myshopify.com/690933842/orders/b1946ac92492d2347c6235b4d2611184/authenticate?key=imasecretipod",
            "payment_gateway_names": [
                "bogus"
            ],
            "phone": "+557734881234",
            "presentment_currency": "USD",
            "processed_at": "2008-01-10T11:00:00-05:00",
            "processing_method": "direct",
            "reference": "fhwdgads",
            "referring_site": "http://www.otherexample.com",
            "source_identifier": "fhwdgads",
            "source_name": "web",
            "source_url": None,
            "subtotal_price": "597.00",
            "subtotal_price_set": {
                "shop_money": {
                    "amount": "597.00",
                    "currency_code": "USD"
                },
                "presentment_money": {
                    "amount": "597.00",
                    "currency_code": "USD"
                }
            },
            "tags": "",
            "tax_lines": [
                {
                    "price": "11.94",
                    "rate": 0.06,
                    "title": "State Tax",
                    "price_set": {
                        "shop_money": {
                            "amount": "11.94",
                            "currency_code": "USD"
                        },
                        "presentment_money": {
                            "amount": "11.94",
                            "currency_code": "USD"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
                            "sku": "IPOD2008GREEN",
                            "taxable": True,
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "requires_shipping": True,
                        },
                        "presentment_money": {
                            "amount": "0.00",
                            "currency_code": "USD"
                        }
                    },
                    "variant_id": 49148385,
                    "variant_inventory_management": "shopify",
                    "variant_title": "red",
                    "vendor": None,
                    "tax_lines": [
                        {
                            "price": "3.98",
                            "price_set": {
                                "shop_money": {
                                    "amount": "3.98",
                                    "currency_code": "USD"
                                },
                                "presentment_money": {
                                    "amount": "3.98",
                                    "currency_code": "USD"
                                }
                            },
                            "rate": 0.06,
                            "title": "State Tax"
                        }
                    ],
                    "discount_allocations": [
                        {
                            "amount": "3.33",
                            "amount_set": {
                                "shop_money": {
                                    "amount": "3.33",
                                    "currency_code": "USD"
                                },
                                "presentment_money": {
                                    "amount": "3.33",
                                    "currency_code": "USD"
                                }
                            },
                            "discount_application_index": 0
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 703073504,
                    "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/LineItem/703073504",
                    "fulfillable_quantity": 0,
                    "fulfillment_service": "manual",
                    "fulfillment_status": None,
                    "gift_card": False,
                    "grams": 200,
                    "name": "IPod Nano - 8gb - black",
                    "price": "199.00",
                    "price_set": {
                        "shop_money": {
                            "amount": "199.00",
                            "currency_code": "USD"
                        },
                        "presentment_money": {
                            "amount": "199.00",
                            "currency_code": "USD"
                        }
                    },
                    "product_exists": True,
                    "product_id": 632910392,
                    "properties": [

                    ],
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "requires_shipping": True,
                    "sku": "IPOD2008BLACK",
                    "taxable": True,
                    "title": "IPod Nano - 8gb",
                    "total_discount": "0.00",
                    "total_discount_set": {
                        "shop_money": {
                            "amount": "0.00",
                            "currency_code": "USD"
                        },
                        "presentment_money": {
                            "amount": "0.00",
                            "currency_code": "USD"
                        }
                    },
                    "variant_id": 457924702,
                    "variant_inventory_management": "shopify",
                    "variant_title": "black",
                    "vendor": None,
                    "tax_lines": [
                        {
                            "price": "3.98",
                            "price_set": {
                                "shop_money": {
                                    "amount": "3.98",
                                    "currency_code": "USD"
                                },
                                "presentment_money": {
                                    "amount": "3.98",
                                    "currency_code": "USD"
                                }
                            },
                            "rate": 0.06,
                            "title": "State Tax"
                        }
                    ],
                    "discount_allocations": [
                        {
                            "amount": "3.33",
                            "amount_set": {
                                "shop_money": {
                                    "amount": "3.33",
                                    "currency_code": "USD"
                                },
                                "presentment_money": {
                                    "amount": "3.33",
                                    "currency_code": "USD"
                                }
                            },
                            "discount_application_index": 0
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "payment_details": {
                "credit_card_bin": None,
                "avs_result_code": None,
                "cvv_result_code": None,
                "credit_card_number": "•••• •••• •••• 4242",
                "credit_card_company": "Visa"
            },
            "refunds": [
                {
                    "id": 509562969,
                    "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/Refund/509562969",
                    "created_at": "2021-09-18T13:31:15-04:00",
                    "note": "it broke during shipping",
                    "order_id": 450789469,
                    "processed_at": "2021-09-18T13:31:15-04:00",
                    "restock": True,
                    "user_id": 799407056,
                    "order_adjustments": [

                    ],
                    "transactions": [
                        {
                            "id": 179259969,
                            "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/OrderTransaction/179259969",
                            "amount": "209.00",
                            "authorization": "authorization-key",
                            "created_at": "2005-08-05T12:59:12-04:00",
                            "currency": "USD",
                            "device_id": None,
                            "error_code": None,
                            "gateway": "bogus",
                            "kind": "refund",
                            "location_id": None,
                            "message": None,
                            "order_id": 450789469,
                            "parent_id": 801038806,
                            "processed_at": "2005-08-05T12:59:12-04:00",
                            "receipt": {

                            },
                            "source_name": "web",
                            "status": "success",
                            "test": False,
                            "user_id": None
                        }
                    ],
                    "refund_line_items": [
                        {
                            "id": 104689539,
                            "line_item_id": 703073504,
                            "location_id": 487838322,
                            "quantity": 1,
                            "restock_type": "legacy_restock",
                            "subtotal": 195.66,
                            "subtotal_set": {
                                "shop_money": {
                                    "amount": "195.66",
                                    "currency_code": "USD"
                                },
                                "presentment_money": {
                                    "amount": "195.66",
                                    "currency_code": "USD"
                                }
                            },
                            "total_tax": 3.98,
                            "total_tax_set": {
                                "shop_money": {
                                    "amount": "3.98",
                                    "currency_code": "USD"
                                },
                                "presentment_money": {
                                    "amount": "3.98",
                                    "currency_code": "USD"
                                }
                            },
                            "line_item": {
                                "id": 703073504,
                                "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/LineItem/703073504",
                                "fulfillable_quantity": 0,
                                "fulfillment_service": "manual",
                                "fulfillment_status": None,
                                "gift_card": False,
                                "grams": 200,
                                "name": "IPod Nano - 8gb - black",
                                "price": "199.00",
                                "price_set": {
                                    "shop_money": {
                                        "amount": "199.00",
                                        "currency_code": "USD"
                                    },
                                    "presentment_money": {
                                        "amount": "199.00",
                                        "currency_code": "USD"
                                    }
                                },
                                "product_exists": True,
                                "product_id": 632910392,
                                "properties": [

                                ],
                                "quantity": 1,
                                "requires_shipping": True,
                                "sku": "IPOD2008BLACK",
                                "taxable": True,
                                "title": "IPod Nano - 8gb",
                                "total_discount": "0.00",
                                "total_discount_set": {
                                    "shop_money": {
                                        "amount": "0.00",
                                        "currency_code": "USD"
                                    },
                                    "presentment_money": {
                                        "amount": "0.00",
                                        "currency_code": "USD"
                                    }
                                },
                                "variant_id": 457924702,
                                "variant_inventory_management": "shopify",
                                "variant_title": "black",
                                "vendor": None,
                                "tax_lines": [
                                    {
                                        "price": "3.98",
                                        "price_set": {
                                            "shop_money": {
                                                "amount": "3.98",
                                                "currency_code": "USD"
                                            },
                                            "presentment_money": {
                                                "amount": "3.98",
                                                "currency_code": "USD"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "rate": 0.06,
                                        "title": "State Tax"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "discount_allocations": [
                                    {
                                        "amount": "3.33",
                                        "amount_set": {
                                            "shop_money": {
                                                "amount": "3.33",
                                                "currency_code": "USD"
                                            },
                                            "presentment_money": {
                                                "amount": "3.33",
                                                "currency_code": "USD"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "discount_application_index": 0
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 709875399,
                            "line_item_id": 466157049,
                            "location_id": 487838322,
                            "quantity": 1,
                            "restock_type": "legacy_restock",
                            "subtotal": 195.67,
                            "subtotal_set": {
                                "shop_money": {
                                    "amount": "195.67",
                                    "currency_code": "USD"
                                },
                                "presentment_money": {
                                    "amount": "195.67",
                                    "currency_code": "USD"
                                }
                            },
                            "total_tax": 3.98,
                            "total_tax_set": {
                                "shop_money": {
                                    "amount": "3.98",
                                    "currency_code": "USD"
                                },
                                "presentment_money": {
                                    "amount": "3.98",
                                    "currency_code": "USD"
                                }
                            },
                            "line_item": {
                                "id": 466157049,
                                "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/LineItem/466157049",
                                "fulfillable_quantity": 0,
                                "fulfillment_service": "manual",
                                "fulfillment_status": None,
                                "gift_card": False,
                                "grams": 200,
                                "name": "IPod Nano - 8gb - green",
                                "price": "199.00",
                                "price_set": {
                                    "shop_money": {
                                        "amount": "199.00",
                                        "currency_code": "USD"
                                    },
                                    "presentment_money": {
                                        "amount": "199.00",
                                        "currency_code": "USD"
                                    }
                                },
                                "product_exists": True,
                                "product_id": 632910392,
                                "properties": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "Custom Engraving Front",
                                        "value": "Happy Birthday"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "Custom Engraving Back",
                                        "value": "Merry Christmas"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "quantity": 1,
                                "requires_shipping": True,
                                "sku": "IPOD2008GREEN",
                                "taxable": True,
                                "title": "IPod Nano - 8gb",
                                "total_discount": "0.00",
                                "total_discount_set": {
                                    "shop_money": {
                                        "amount": "0.00",
                                        "currency_code": "USD"
                                    },
                                    "presentment_money": {
                                        "amount": "0.00",
                                        "currency_code": "USD"
                                    }
                                },
                                "variant_id": 39072856,
                                "variant_inventory_management": "shopify",
                                "variant_title": "green",
                                "vendor": None,
                                "tax_lines": [
                                    {
                                        "price": "3.98",
                                        "price_set": {
                                            "shop_money": {
                                                "amount": "3.98",
                                                "currency_code": "USD"
                                            },
                                            "presentment_money": {
                                                "amount": "3.98",
                                                "currency_code": "USD"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "rate": 0.06,
                                        "title": "State Tax"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "discount_allocations": [
                                    {
                                        "amount": "3.34",
                                        "amount_set": {
                                            "shop_money": {
                                                "amount": "3.34",
                                                "currency_code": "USD"
                                            },
                                            "presentment_money": {
                                                "amount": "3.34",
                                                "currency_code": "USD"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "discount_application_index": 0
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "shipping_address": {
                "first_name": "Bob",
                "address1": "Chestnut Street 92",
                "phone": "555-625-1199",
                "city": "Louisville",
                "zip": "40202",
                "province": "Kentucky",
                "country": "United States",
                "last_name": "Norman",
                "address2": "",
                "company": None,
                "latitude": 45.41634,
                "longitude": -75.6868,
                "name": "Bob Norman",
                "country_code": "US",
                "province_code": "KY"
            },
            "shipping_lines": [
                {
                    "id": 369256396,
                    "carrier_identifier": None,
                    "code": "Free Shipping",
                    "delivery_category": None,
                    "discounted_price": "0.00",
                    "discounted_price_set": {
                        "shop_money": {
                            "amount": "0.00",
                            "currency_code": "USD"
                        },
                        "presentment_money": {
                            "amount": "0.00",
                            "currency_code": "USD"
                        }
                    },
                    "phone": None,
                    "price": "0.00",
                    "price_set": {
                        "shop_money": {
                            "amount": "0.00",
                            "currency_code": "USD"
                        },
                        "presentment_money": {
                            "amount": "0.00",
                            "currency_code": "USD"
                        }
                    },
                    "requested_fulfillment_service_id": None,
                    "source": "shopify",
                    "title": "Free Shipping",
                    "tax_lines": [

                    ],
                    "discount_allocations": [

                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

orders = [flatten(o) for o in data['orders']]
df = pd.DataFrame(orders)
print(df)
```